# ubuntu: totem asking for a flash demuxer plugin and not playing flv videos

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, flash, plugins, totem

I have ubuntu karmic os (9.10). Totem was the default movie player. It used to play flv files as well. Now all of a sudden it asks for a flash demuxer plugin and refuses to play flv files. How to fix this?

Comment: you should try VLC instead of totem. just sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: yes thanx vlc works!!!